# grpc client talking to REST server through envoy

Tags: rest, grpc, grpc-java, envoyproxy

I am trying to do grpc request to rest server through envoy, I am able to run my envoy on port 80 and server is running on port 81. grpc client is set to make a call to port 80. But when I run client, I am getting error:

`io.grpc.StatusRuntimeException: UNIMPLEMENTED`

Here is my envoy yaml

```
static_resources:
  listeners:
    - name: listener_0
      address:
        socket_address:
          address: 0.0.0.0
          port_value: 8080
      filter_chains:
        - filters:
            - name: envoy.http_connection_manager
              typed_config:
                "@type": type.googleapis.com/envoy.extensions.filters.network.http_connection_manager.v3.HttpConnectionManager
                access_log:
                  - name: envoy.access_loggers.stdout
                    typed_config:
                      "@type": type.googleapis.com/envoy.extensions.access_loggers.stream.v3.StdoutAccessLog
                codec_type: auto
                stat_prefix: ingress_http
                route_config:
                  name: local_route
                  virtual_hosts:
                    - name: backend
                      domains: ["*"]
                      routes:
                        - match: { prefix: "/sample" }
                          route:
                            cluster: http4s_server_cluster
                http_filters:
                  - name: envoy.filters.http.grpc_http1_reverse_bridge
                    typed_config:
                      "@type": type.googleapis.com/envoy.extensions.filters.http.grpc_http1_reverse_bridge.v3.FilterConfig
                      content_type: application/grpc
                      withhold_grpc_frames: true
                  - name: envoy.filters.http.router
                    typed_config:
                      "@type": type.googleapis.com/envoy.extensions.filters.http.router.v3.Router
  clusters:
    - name: http4s_server_cluster
      connect_timeout: 0.25s
      type: strict_dns
      lb_policy: round_robin
      http2_protocol_options: {}
      load_assignment:
        cluster_name: http4s_server_cluster
        endpoints:
          - lb_endpoints:
              - endpoint:
                  address:
                    socket_address:
                      address: 127.0.0.1
                      port_value: 8081 # Assuming the HTTP4s server is running on localhost:8081
```

My rest server does not have any information about proto files, it is simple rest server that returns json response.

This is my first time configuring, do I need something in server side?